# Why does the code . shortcut not work on OSX?

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I've tried adding the 'code .' [shortcut](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup) to launch your current directory in Terminal in Visual Studio Code, but I was promptly returned the following error:

```
LSGetApplicationForInfo() failed with error -10814 while trying to 
determine the application with bundle identifier com.microsoft.VSCode.
```

Visual Studio Code is installed on my machine successfully.

I'm using OSX Yosemite 10.10.3.

Does anybody know how to get this shortcut to work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have Visual Studio Code 0.3.0 installed. We recently changed the bundle identifier!

Comment: When I asked Code to check for updates, it tells me there are no updates. I checked the version and I was on 0.1.0 ( :O ). I updated it manually. Now the command works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This error is because Finder cannot locate Visual Studio Code. I can reproduce the same error on my machine by deleting Visual Studio Code.

Try re-installing VS Code to **/Applications** and restarting Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Press `command` + `shift` + `p`

Type: `Install 'code' command in path`

Choose the option