# VSCode: 'code' function is preventing me from launching code from shell

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code

I install [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for MacOS and installed the `code` command to the shell via the GUI.

[image]

Now, when I try to execute this command, I get the following error:

> LSGetApplicationForInfo() failed with error -10814 while trying to determine the application with bundle identifier com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders.

I have no idea what is the cause of this. I found that a function `code` has also been created and that if I remove it with `unset code` once, I can then run `code` in the shell and VSCode will launch correctly. Every reboot bring back this function though...

The `code` function is:

```
# type code
code is a function
code ()
{
    VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders" --args $*
}
```

What is the problem? What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: If `unset code` makes it work, it means you have a function named `code` either in system profile or in your local profile. You can still execute VSCode without unsetting the function code by running `command code`. This will execute the script and not the function. But I suggest getting rid of the function code.

Comment: I notice that the error has a mention to VSCodeInsiders. You might have more success with the stable version rather than the insider version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `code` function was created from [some other file](https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/.functions#L175) I was using before even installing Visual Studio code and was then conflicting with the executable installed by the app under `/usr/local/bin/code`.

Answer (score 1):

I have it installed in my Mac, and there is no alias. I do not need to unset anything. 'code' is just a script file, residing in `/usr/local/bin/code

It seems you have a conflict with some other application that has set an alias for 'code'. I recommend you look at all scripts that are run during shell startup:

```
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile
~/.inputrc
/etc/profile
```

It could also help if you post the content of your code alias

Comment: When a command can resolve to multiple paths and aliases, in order to determine which one is the option picked by the shell, use the `type code` command. If it is an alias, it shouldn't. Check why is it.

Comment: glad it worked! using code from the command line is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This may relate to a conflict with another application.

A couple things to try:

- Reinstall VSCode
- Check for Updates in VSCode since they recently updated their bundler.

This is an issue I recently ran into and was able to resolve through reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue that occurs when you have an unintentionally outdated version where the bundle identifier is outdated.

Try manually updating VS Code to get started- just to be sure this isn't the issue.

[Be sure you are running 1.11.2](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)

[code . shortcut fails on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653095/code-shortcut-fails-on-osx)

EDIT: Also, I still don't know why MS use negative signs in error codes. [It's generally bad practice.](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2016/07/dont-use-negative-numbers-for-error-codes/)